# How can write scraped content to a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need some help to save the output from a basic web scraper to a CSV file.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

html_ = urlopen("some_url")
bsObj_ = BeautifulSoup(html_, "html.parser")
nameList_ = bsObj_2.findAll("div", {"class":"row proyecto_name_venta"})

for name in nameList_:

    print(name.get_text())
```

Specifically, I want to save the `name.get_text()` result in a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty comprehensive example of what you asked for . . . .

```
import urllib2

listOfStocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "AMZN"]

urls = []

for company in listOfStocks:
    urls.append('http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=' + company + '&d=6&e=28&f=2015&g=m&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv')

Output_File = open('C:/Users/rshuell001/Historical_Prices.csv','w')

New_Format_Data = ''

for counter in range(0, len(urls)):

    Original_Data = urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).read()

    if counter == 0:
        New_Format_Data = "Company," + urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).readline()

    rows = Original_Data.splitlines(1)

    for row in range(1, len(rows)):

        New_Format_Data = New_Format_Data + listOfStocks[counter] + ',' + rows[row]

Output_File.write(New_Format_Data)
Output_File.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the elements in `nameList_` are rows with the columns delimited by `','` try this:

```
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    writer.writerows(name.get_text().split(',') for name nameList_)
```

If `nameList_.get_text()` is just a string and you want to write a single column CSV, you might try this:

```
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    writer.writerows([name.get_text()] for name in nameList_)
```

Comment: As the code is for Python 3, the `csv` module requires `open` with the extra argument `with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as outf: ...`. You may also need to add the argument `encoding='utf-8'`. For Python 2, the binary mode is required like `open('out.csv', 'wb')`. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html ]