# write a CSV file with Python after scraping text from website

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-mining

I'm trying to write a CSV file after scraping text from website. I already found this answer: [How can write scraped content to a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580286/how-can-write-scraped-content-to-a-csv-file) but it doesn't solve my problem.

The problem is that I got only one row after writing the CSV file.

This is my code so far (I used `bs4` and `mechanize`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

url = "https://www.contratos.gov.co/consultas/detalleProceso.do?numConstancia=15-12-3634534"
br = mechanize.Browser()
search = br.open(url)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

response = search.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
text = soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'tablaslistOdd'})
for t in text:
    result = t.text.replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace('\n', '')
    newResult = result.encode('utf-8')
    #print newResult
    for line in newResult:
        output = open('data/myCSVfile.csv', 'w')
        output.write(newResult)
        output.close()
```

What I'm looking for is to write for each line of text a CSV column. 
Is this possible?
Any suggestions to solve the problem are appreciated!

Comment: Open the file once **outside** the loop

Comment: and close it outside of the loop too. Good luck to all.

Comment: Hi, @PadraicCunningham! I think is a different question. Perhaps I need to edit the question in order to be more clear :)

Comment: @estebanpdl, Does opening outside the loop fix the problem?

Comment: I just edited the question. Partially it fixed the problem. What I'm trying to code is _for each line write a CSV column_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each time you close the file and open it, it rewrites what is in there. So you need not to close it. For example, your code to write the csv may look like this:

```
with open('data/myCSVfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in newResult:
        f.write(newResult + '\n')
```

---

By the way, `with` statement allows you not to care about closing the file - it closes it for you. It's a good practice to use it, because it makes your code cleaner and closes the file right after you don't need it.

---

To get the format you want try this:

```
import csv

lines = []
for t in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'tablaslistOdd'}):
    text = t.text.replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace('\n', '').encode('utf-8')
    lines.append(text)

with open('myCSVfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. However, how can I wrote those in columns, not rows.

Comment: Nice! Could you please add an example of an output that you get now and the output you want to your question?

Comment: Sure. I'm going to edit the question right away!

Comment: @estebanpdl, if you are not getting the format you expect, you should ask a new question in relation to that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I think it isn't worth the trouble - probably all that's needed is a newline charater after each line. So the answer the another question would either include answer for this one or would just be incredibly small.

Comment: @IlyaPeterov, well now your answer no longer answers the question as it has completely changed, if an edit completely changes  a question it usually means the OP needs to ask a new question.

Comment: @IlyaPeterov Question edited :) I hope it is more clear now :)

Comment: @IlyaPeterov Just what I was looking for. Thanks for your support :)